# React Material-ui button disabled property not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I can't make the property [disabled] for my material-ui button work.

Props are coming from the parent component, it's mainly strings.
Deck is an array of cards.

Here's my code :

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import AddIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Add";

export default class Card extends React.Component {
  state = {...};

  addToDeckClick = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.addToDeck();
    this.toggleShowDescription();
  };

  isCardInDeck = () => {
    return this.props.deck.some(
      (card) => card.translationKey === this.props.card.translationKey
    );
  };

  addToDeck = () => {
    if (!this.isCardInDeck()) {
      this.props.deck.push(this.props.card);
    }
  };

  isAddButtonDisabled = () => {
    return !this.isCardInDeck();
  };

  render() {
    return (
          ...
          <Button
            disabled={this.isAddButtonDisabled()}
            className="addDeck"
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            onClick={this.addToDeckClick}
            startIcon={<AddIcon />}
          >
            Add to deck
          </Button>
          ...              
     );
  }
}
```

I tried several syntaxes :

```
disabled={this.isAddButtonDisabled}
disabled={this.isAddButtonDisabled()}
disabled={() => this.isAddButtonDisabled()}
```

But can't make it work. Any ideas ?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component doesn't render when you add to deck.

```
this.setState({showDescription: true})
```

and also add the state to disabled logic:

```
<Button
    disabled={this.isCardInDeck() && this.state.showDescription}
```

I'd recommend you make your card a simple component with no state just props providing display logic. Move your state to the parent component that holds the cards.

```
class CardHolder extends React.Component {
    state = {
        userDeck: [],
        cards: [],
        showCardId: null
    };

    addToDeck = (cardId)=>{
        this.setState({
            showCardId: cardId,
            userDeck: [...this.state.userDeck, cardId]
        })
    }
    redner(){

        return this.state.cards.map(card=>{

            return <Card 
                onAddToDeck={this.addToDeck}
                disabled={this.state.userDeck.includes(card.id)}
                title={card.title}
            />
        })
    }
}

function Card(props){
    return (
        <div>
            <Button
                disabled={props.disabled}
                className="addDeck"
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                onClick={props.onAddToDeck}
                startIcon={<AddIcon />}
            >
                Add to deck
        </Button>
            <div onClick={props.onSelectCard}>
                {props.title}
                {props.icon}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: This is working now but the status of the button is not refreshed instantly, I have to hide the div and display it again to see the button disabled.

Comment: @AnthonyDa Look at the update, not very optimized but will do the job

Comment: I think I did something wrong, could you take a look at my sandbox please ?
https://codesandbox.io/s/htstranslator-n3p04

Comment: @xlsra I sorted a few things out, the onClick is working but I still have the issue on the disabled property